# Run lerna bootstrap on CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, lerna

I'm using lerna to manage a monorepo.
I have this kind of structure:

packages
-- app
-- dependency1
-- dependency2
app uses dependency1 and dependency2, dependency1 uses also dependency2.
The main thing here we want to deploy is app, let's say it's a webapp.

So, if I want to work locally, I would run lerna bootstrap. This would install dependencies in each of the packages and link them so I can see the changes while developing.

Now, I commit and push to my repo (gitlab, but it would be the same for any other one). Maybe I'm wrong, but what seems logical to me is:

- git checkout branch
- git remote set-url origin so lerna can push to the repo the package.json changes
- run lerna publish to see which packages changed and publish them to the npm repo and commit to git repo the package.json changes.
- navigate to the app folder and install packages (this would also install the published ones in previous step)
- run the build and deployment scripts

I would say we wouldn't need to run lerna bootstrap, this is would install all dependencies in each package and link them, right? I just need to deploy the webapp. Also, if I just changed one package, I don't have to install dependencies in all of the packages.

If I have a bunch of packages more, CI takes ages, with out needing, in my view...

I see a few examples online where lerna bootstrap is always part of the CI. Is this the right approach?